# step between screen - react-native

Tags: react-native

I have a step in reactjs which allows me to go from one component to another and the data that is placed in the input is not deleted but remains, but when wanting to do the same in react-native it is not possible because the Fields are handled with TextInput and not input with reactjs.

this is the package i am using

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-step-builder/v/2.0.10

I would like to pass the following data from my input to TextInput:

```
<input 
        name="organizador"
        value={props.getState('organizador', '')} 
        onChange={props.handleChange}      
      />
```

I want this to work for me but in a "TextInput" of reactNative

Comment: Will [defaultValue](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#defaultvalue) prop not work for you ?

Comment: Yes but it does not work

Comment: Then use a state variable for TextInput value but initialize the state variable via prop.
Something like this - 
```this.state = { textValue: props.getState('organizador', '') }```
and then use state variable in TextInput as below
```<TextInput value={this.state.textValue} onChange={props.handleChange} />```